# Why do I get index value inside column value when I do pandas groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as follows:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame()
df['year'] = ['2015','2015','2016','2016','2017','2017']
df['months'] = [2,4,4,2,3,5]
df['perc'] = ['25','35','55','75','34','38']
```

Which results in dataframe:

```
year  months perc
0  2015       2   25
1  2015       4   35
2  2016       4   55
3  2016       2   75
4  2017       3   34
5  2017       5   38
```

When I do a pandas groupby on year column, the resultant dataframe/pandasgroupby object has index of original DF and the year inside the year column.

Command used:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('year',as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(1, ['months'])))
```

Where the year column has index of original DF (the 1, 2, 5) with the year value:

```
year  months perc
0 1  2015       4   35
1 2  2016       4   55
2 5  2017       5   38
```

print(result['year']) gives:

```
0  1    2015
1  2    2016
2  5    2017
Name: year, dtype: object
```

Why Do I get index of original dataframe inside the year column and how to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is you expected output, but use `group_keys=False` as parameter to only keep the original index:

```
(df.groupby('year',as_index=False, group_keys=False)
   .apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(1, ['months']))
)
```

output:

```
   year  months perc
1  2015       4   35
2  2016       4   55
5  2017       5   38
```